# Paint shape with flutter customPainter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

How i can paint something like this in flutter with CustomPainter:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqsnU.png)

Comment: Have you checked this tutorial? [Video](https://youtu.be/vvI_NUXK00s)

Comment: yep, but i don't understand that much, to acheive the rounded container I want

Answer (score 1):

Try this and tweak the values to your convenience

```
class CurvedBarPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint() 
    ..color = Colors.black;

    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height * .58);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .01, size.height * .95 , size.width * .15, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .85, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .99, size.height * .95 , size.width, size.height * .6);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * .2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .99, size.height * -.02, size.width * .9, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .8, 0.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .7, size.height * .01, size.width * .65, size.height * .3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .5, size.height , size.width * .35, size.height * .3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .3, size.height * .01, size.width * .2, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .1, 0.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .01, size.height * -.02, 0.0, size.height * .2);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;

}
```